# MySQL 5.6 full text search query not return rows result

Tags: mysql

This query doesn't return any results in MySQL 5.6:

```
SELECT * FROM company WHERE match(name) against('*Hotel*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) and is_visible=1 and is_system_company=1 and language_content='en'
```

if I execute this query in MySQL 5.7 it returns rows correctly.

What is the problem?

Comment: We need table structures and some example data.. We can't reverse engineer your problem with only a SQL query.

Comment: Does the table use the same engine in both databases? And does the "company" table have a FULLTEXT index on "name" in both?